# Does Bitcoin accept HYIP website?

Tags: payment

I'm running a HYIP website I'm considering to use Bitcoin. Does Bitcoin have a limit on funding or withdrawal amount? Is there any chance Bitcoin blocks my account because I receive money from a HYIP website?
Thank you.

Comment: Bitcoin's not a person or organization. It's a network of computers, and it doesn't care about your intent.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way one can have his account blocked in Bitcoin and there are no funding or withdrawal amounts limits. However, you should take into account that all Bitcoin is pseudo-anonymous, i.e. although there is no direct connection between you and your account address, all transactions are public and could be tracked by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is a communication protocol, it doesn't have policies. It is like asking if TCP/IP allows porn.